# объединение двух DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Всех приветствую!

У меня есть DataFrame:

```
   A   B   C   D
1  1   2   3   4
2  1   2   3   4
3  1   2   3   4
4  1   2   3   4
5  1   2   3   4
```

И еще один:

```
    A    B    C   D
1  11   22   33   44
2  11   22   33   44
3  11   22   33   44
4  11   22   33   44
5  11   22   33   44
```

Как я могу их объединить, чтобы получилось так:

```
  A   B   C   D
1  1   2   3   4
2  1   2   3   4
3  1   2   3   4
4  1   2   3   4
5  1   2   3   4
6  11  22  33  44
7  11  22  33  44
8  11  22  33  44
9  11  22  33  44
10 11  22  33  44
```

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2])` - вы хоть пробовали поискать решение и почитать документацию?

Answer (score 1):

Да, здесь подходят два метода:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

и

```
df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Не забудьте включить флаг `ignore_index`, чтобы индексация не сбилась :)